# HTML parsing using PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am trying to parse the source code of this particular web page:
http://www.sns.gov.uk/Reports/Report.aspx?ReportId=1&PostCode=EH1%201HN

The thing is that when I use the code below:

```
$url = 'http://www.sns.gov.uk/Reports/Report.aspx?ReportId=1&PostCode=EH1%201HN';
$output = file_get_contents($url); 
echo htmlspecialchars( $output );
```

I get the source code of http://www.sns.gov.uk without the extra information I want.

Do you have any idea why is this happening and the possible solution to that?

Comment: You mean your `file_get_contents()` call delivers another URL than what you expect? Then most likely you have some form of session issue. So that the desired URL cannot be called directly, but only in the context of some session.

Comment: to be more specific @arkascha , the correct process would be to enter a information in http://www.sns.gov.uk  and then it will be created the next web page that i want to render. So propably the URL cannot be called directly like you wrote. In that case what should i do?

Comment: Check the raw http request,especially request header and body,make sure the cookie,referer,origin,etc are the same.

Comment: And also consider if what you try to do is really legitim...

Comment: can you elaborate what excactly should i check @PHPJungle. I am a rockie in web coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tool (like **[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)**) to capture the HTTP Request:

```
GET http://www.sns.gov.uk/Reports/Report.aspx?ReportId=1&PostCode=EH1%201HN HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sns.gov.uk
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.sns.gov.uk/default.aspx?DisplayMessage=False
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4,ja;q=0.2
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yn1jfjwgzhc5eobnskqux1mm; sessionCookie=isConnected=false; UsrSession=UserGUID=7a8e0dc4-4346-437d-ac80-393d8fa4fc8e; GWCensus=SessionGUID={3ab2206e-9e0f-4602-8fb7-972cb1f5338c}; civicAllowCookies=yes; __utmt=1; __utmt_~1=1; __utmt_~2=1; __utma=82977748.1471390697.1435401464.1435401464.1435401464.1; __utmb=82977748.5.10.1435401464; __utmc=82977748; __utmz=82977748.1435401464.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/31087581/html-parsing-using-php
```

[image]

```
This picutre exactly shows what you need to build your HTTP Request:
1.GET method;
2.Referer;
3.Cookie (!important)
```

Comment: see the [HTTP Protocol wiki](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm)

Comment: thank you for your response, the thing is that i should implement this in php, so as to able to fetch the data afterwards. But i don't know why. I guess i should implenet a specific function and in the parameters i should enet the 1,2,3 you mention above @PHPJungle

Comment: See my Github [iHttp.php](https://github.com/phpjungle/iHttp),it's my class you can easily send HTTP Request and get server response.also it supports server proxy etc

Comment: here is my code @PHPJungle which i took from you, but it didn't work   http://codepad.org/aAhiBa4U

Comment: i won't sleep, so send me the code whenever you want!! thank you for your help :) :)

Comment: Okay just wait for several mins

Comment: [This is my code](http://codepad.org/tQczwqa7) , I spent long time to modify my iHttp.php ,beacuse I added some new method to the class. eg:parse_response_header(), parse_reaponse_cookie

Comment: i am literally speechless!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I have updated my git codes in ihttp just now,remember to update yours ihttp.php

Comment: i have one more question. If i want to parse some specific data from this page, so as to have the number of households, how should i do that @PHPJungle ?

Comment: what app do you use to communicate with your friends? We can use this to chat

Comment: fb, skype. Do you propose something else? I don't have enough reputation to chat from here unfortunatelly :(

Comment: Use **regular expression or [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)** to parse the html data you want